# Enthought EDM Python won't install packages with Python 3.4

Tags: python-3.x, enthought

Enthought's EDM won't create an environment for Python 3.4.

```
edm environments create for-pyinstaller --version 3.4
Fetching indices for runtime repositories. done
Installing runtime... done
Fetching indices for package repositories.. done
No candidate found for requirement 'pip'

Did you mean this?
    sip
```

And then once I'm in that environment, I can't download anything with edm install:

```
edm install numpy
Fetching indices for package repositories.. done
No candidate found for requirement 'numpy'
```

Is there a way to use python 3.4 with EDM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to use python 3.4 with EDM?

Not realistically. Substantial support for Python 3 in EDM begins with Python 3.5, and is currently focused on Python 3.6.